# Sum of Sum, unroll terms

Tags: sympy

I'm especting something like the following:

```
>>> Sum(x[i,j],(j, i+1, 3), (i, 1, 3)).doit()
x[1,2] + x[1,3] + x[2,3]
```

But instead I get:

```
>>> Sum(x[i,j],(j, i+1, 3), (i, 1, 3)).doit()
Sum(x[i,j],(j, i+1, 3), (i, 1, 3))
```

Anybody knows how to make the first one?

I'm not looking for a solution like the following:

```
>>> sum(x[i,j] for i in range(1,4) for j in range(i,4))
x[1,2] + x[1,3] + x[2,3]
```

This is intended for computing drift forces where the number of combinations is way bigger and the inside term is more complex, but I need away to get it without the summation form.

Comment: `summations.eval_sum_direct` handles the expansion logic, for constant bounds smaller than 100. Since the bounds for `j` are not constant (depends on `i`), it does not move on to try and evaluate the outer bounds. Covering this kind of bounds cases would require specific extension for the `eval_sum` function.